# Unable to upload files to server by jQuery file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, file-upload, handler

I am trying to upload a file to the server side by jQuery file upload (http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/). My client is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
       $('#fileupload').fileupload({
           url: 'attachmentsHandler.ashx',
            replaceFileInput: false,
            dataType: 'json',
           done: function (e, data) {
               $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
                   $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
               });
           },
           add: function (e, data) {
                   data.submit();
           }
       });
   });
```

On the server side I have a simple handler with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
public class attachmentsHandler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        //context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        string path = context.Server.MapPath("~/attachments");
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        var file = context.Request.Files[0];
        string fileName = Path.Combine(path + file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(fileName);
        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        var result = new { name = fileName };
        context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(result));

    }
    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting a timeout on evaluating context.Request.Files.

Comment: I am my client in IE11

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the `ProcessRequest` method and examine the request to make sure it looks valid.

Comment: The request looks valid. It just doesn't have Files in context.Request. The content length is approximately same as file size.

Comment: Have you set the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` for either the form or the file input element?

Comment: I don't have a form object, so added this to the input. Made no difference.I can upload files by form submission, but wanted to avoid that as it opens a new window.

Comment: I assumed there'd be a form with it being a .Net application, but you're right - it doesn't matter that there isn't.  I'm afraid I'm out of suggestions.  That's pretty much the same code I used with the same file upload library and an ashx file and it worked for me.  I'll keep looking to see if anything jumps out at me though.

Comment: Try adding a `fail` event handler to the fileupload, in the same way you have `done` and `add`... `fail: function (e, data) { console.log("upload fail"); console.dir(e); console.dir(data); }`

Comment: Not a problem thanks for your help. I was able to solve my problem with form submit.

Comment: No worries - glad you got it working :)